# Plot a bar using matplotlib using a dictionary

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Is there any way to plot a bar plot using `matplotlib` using data directly from a dict?

My dict looks like this:

```
D = {u'Label1':26, u'Label2': 17, u'Label3':30}
```

I was expecting

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5.5,3),dpi=300)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
bar = ax.bar(D,range(1,len(D)+1,1),0.5)
```

to work, but it does not.

Here is the error:

```
>>> ax.bar(D,range(1,len(D)+1,1),0.5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.py", line 4904, in bar
    self.add_patch(r)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.py", line 1570, in add_patch
    self._update_patch_limits(p)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.py", line 1588, in _update_patch_limits
    xys = patch.get_patch_transform().transform(vertices)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/patches.py", line 580, in get_patch_transform
    self._update_patch_transform()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/patches.py", line 576, in _update_patch_transform
    bbox = transforms.Bbox.from_bounds(x, y, width, height)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 786, in from_bounds
    return Bbox.from_extents(x0, y0, x0 + width, y0 + height)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, float found
```

Comment: Can you share specifically what does not work? Do you get an exception? What exception? Share as much information as possible.

Comment: @InbarRose sorry, I have updated the question with the error it shows... something concerning string or buffer... I don't understand this error message.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve, but in `ax.bar(D,range(1,len(D)+1,1),0.5)` the first argument should be a list of numbers, in your case `D.values()`.

Comment: @adrianp I know it can't work... but what I tried to do is to just plot a bar chart with one line, giving it the strings and values at once. I tough maybe there is a way to add data and labels at the same time... but `D.values()` was also new for me and it's pretty cool.

Comment: A one-liner is not possible for this, at least to my knowledge.

Comment: You might want to submit a feature request to the github site for this, because it does seem useful.

Comment: Usefull or not, it seems "natural" :-)

Answer (score 206, accepted):

You can do it in two lines by first plotting the bar chart and then setting the appropriate ticks:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

D = {u'Label1':26, u'Label2': 17, u'Label3':30}

plt.bar(range(len(D)), list(D.values()), align='center')
plt.xticks(range(len(D)), list(D.keys()))
# # for python 2.x:
# plt.bar(range(len(D)), D.values(), align='center')  # python 2.x
# plt.xticks(range(len(D)), D.keys())  # in python 2.x

plt.show()
```

Note that the penultimate line should read `plt.xticks(range(len(D)), list(D.keys()))` in python3, because `D.keys()` returns a generator, which matplotlib cannot use directly.

Comment: you can of course wrap those two lines up in a function and then it becomes a one-liner ;)

Comment: If you use figure and axes objects, it's `ax.set_xticklabels`

Comment: thanks! But I have some estetic issues with plt.xticks, could you please tell us how to move them vertically from horizontally.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you elaborate on what you mean by moving sticks vertically from horizontally?

Comment: are the key-value pairs aligned when the dict is not sorted?

Comment: Python dicts cannot be sorted. Consequently, the order is always arbitrary. However, the keys and values are always aligned with the above code.

Comment: Note that this does not work in python 3.x. You'd have to write something like `list(D.keys())`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31755900/python-3-xs-dictionary-view-objects-and-matplotlib for further details.

Comment: (new to matplotlib) I seemed to have to do plt.hist(D) before the plt.show().  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: To plot n columns, like this: d = { 'u1':26,56,n..., 'u2':34,45,...}, what I have to change in the script?

Comment: It's not clear what you want the plot to look like. Could you post an example image in a separate question?

Comment: Using a dictionary is probably a bad idea, since the bars will always show up in a random order!

Comment: matplotlib can take `keys` as an arg now so can reduce to one line and simplify like: `plt.bar(D.keys(), D.values(), align='center')`

Answer (score 113):

It's a little simpler than most answers here suggest:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

D = {u'Label1':26, u'Label2': 17, u'Label3':30}
plt.bar(*zip(*D.items()))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: this should be the answer. tnx

Answer (score 41):

For future reference, the above code does not work with Python 3. For Python 3, the `D.keys()` needs to be converted to a list.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

D = {u'Label1':26, u'Label2': 17, u'Label3':30}

plt.bar(range(len(D)), D.values(), align='center')
plt.xticks(range(len(D)), list(D.keys()))

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 16):

Why not just:

```
names, counts = zip(*D.items())
plt.bar(names, counts)
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

The best way to implement it using `matplotlib.pyplot.bar(range, height, tick_label)` where the range provides scalar values for the positioning of the corresponding bar in the graph. `tick_label` does the same work as `xticks()`. One can replace it with an integer also and use multiple `plt.bar(integer, height, tick_label)`. For detailed information please refer the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'apple': 67, 'mango': 60, 'lichi': 58}
names = list(data.keys())
values = list(data.values())

#tick_label does the some work as plt.xticks()
plt.bar(range(len(data)),values,tick_label=names)
plt.savefig('bar.png')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Additionally the same plot can be generated without using `range()`. But the problem encountered was that `tick_label` just worked for the last `plt.bar()` call. Hence `xticks()` was used for labelling:

```
data = {'apple': 67, 'mango': 60, 'lichi': 58}
names = list(data.keys())
values = list(data.values())
plt.bar(0,values[0],tick_label=names[0])
plt.bar(1,values[1],tick_label=names[1])
plt.bar(2,values[2],tick_label=names[2])
plt.xticks(range(0,3),names)
plt.savefig('fruit.png')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I often load the dict into a pandas DataFrame then use the plot function of the DataFrame. 
Here is the one-liner:

```
pandas.DataFrame(D, index=['quantity']).plot(kind='bar')
```

[image: resulting plot]

Answer (score 6):

Why not just:

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.barplot(list(D.keys()), list(D.values()))
```

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way for creating a bar graph from dictionary in python is using built-in function of python for dictionaries to retrive data,
so if we had a dict like this:

```
values = {"foo":1,"bar":2,"hey":3}
```

we can create a bar plot like this:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(values.keys(),values.values())
```

[complete code and figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93quv.png)

Comment: Please edit and change the variable name `dict` to something different (data, values, etc.). The code above works, but rewrites the built-in function.