# Using dictionary to make a matplotlib graph?

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib

If I had a dictionary of words and their frequency in a string, for example:

```
{'hello': 3, 'how': 4, 'yes': 10, 'you': 11, 'days': 10, 'are': 20, 'ago': 11}
```

How could I make a bar graph out of this using matplotlib? I found a previous question which had a seemingly good solution, but it didn't work for me ([python: plot a bar using matplotlib using a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010869/python-plot-a-bar-using-matplotlib-using-a-dictionary))

When I run

```
plt.bar(range(len(d)), d.values(), align="center")
plt.xticks(range(len(d)), d.keys())
```

I get the error

```
TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing
```

I don't really see where I'm indexing my dictionary. It might be because in the question from which I got the code the x-values were also numbers? I'm not sure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try wrapping your `d.keys()` in a `list()` call:

```
plt.bar(range(len(d)), d.values(), align="center")
plt.xticks(range(len(d)), list(d.keys()))
```

In Python3, `dict.keys()` doesn't return the list of keys directly, but instead returns a generator that will give you the keys one at a time as you use it.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you! I'll keep in mind that's how dict.keys() works.

Comment: This isn't very relevant to my question, but is there any way I can automate the space between the bars so that all the words can fit on the x-axis (or maybe make the words go to a new line?)

Comment: @Howcan maybe you'd like to split the long words to multiple lines?

Answer (score 1):

On **" is there any way I can automate the space between the bars so that all the words can fit on the x-axis (or maybe make the words go to a new line?)"**

I will split the long words to multiple lines, e.g., `'looooooooongWord'` to `'looooo-\noooong-\nWord'`:

```
In [300]: d={'hello': 3, 'how': 4, 'yes': 10, 'you': 11, 'days': 10, 'are': 20, 'ago': 11, 'looooooooongWord': 10}
     ...: plt.bar(range(len(d)), d.values(), align="center")
     ...: plt.xticks(range(len(d)), [split_word(i) for i in d.keys()])
```

where `split_word` is defined as:

```
In [595]: def split_word(s):
     ...:     n=6
     ...:     return '-\n'.join(s[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(s), n))
     ...: split_word('looooooooongWord')
Out[595]: 'looooo-\noooong-\nWord'
```

[image]