# Tallying the outcome of a coin flip

Tags: python, matplotlib, presentation

I have written a little piece of code for modelling the outcome of a coin flip, and would like to find a better way of presenting the results than a list of consecutive coin flips. I'm one month into learning Python as part of my physics degree, if that helps provide some context.

Here's the code;

```
from pylab import *

x=0
while x<=100:

    num = randint(0,2)
    if num == 0:
        print 'Heads'
    else:
        print 'Tails'
    x=x+1
print 'Done'
```

What options do I have to present this data in an easier to interpret manner?

Comment: take a look at `matplotlib` module python

Comment: Somewhat annoyingly,  `randint(a,b)` does **not** use the same argument convention as `range()` or `xrange()`.  `randint(a,b)` will return a random integer n: a <= n <= b. So your simulated coin is a bit wonky. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using a `while` loop and printing results to the screen, Python can do the counting and store the results very neatly using [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), a subclass of the built in dictionary container.

For example:

```
from collections import Counter
import random

Counter(random.choice(['H', 'T']) for _ in range(100))
```

When I ran the code, it produced the following tally:

```
Counter({'H': 52, 'T': 48})
```

We can see that heads was flipped 52 times and tails 48 times.

This is already much easier to interpret, but now that you have the data in a data structure you can also plot a simple bar chart.

Following the suggestions in a Stack Overflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010869/python-plot-a-bar-using-matplotlib-using-a-dictionary), you could write:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# tally = Counter({'H': 52, 'T': 48})

plt.bar(range(len(tally)), tally.values(), width=0.5, align='center')
plt.xticks(range(len(tally)), ['H', 'T'])
plt.show()
```

This produces a bar chart which looks like this:

[image]

Comment: `Counter` is neat. I've been using `defaultdict(lambda: 0)` all the time.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I'm looking forward to putting this to use.