# How to plot a histogram in python from data in notepad file?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to plot a histogram in python based on some data in a notepad file. 
My notepad file contains 10000 lines, in each line I have ten hypothesis numbers from 0 to 255:

```
....
....
[205 246  19  68 118  44  45  72 210 162]
[205 246  19  68 118  44  45  72 210 162]
[205 246  19  68 118  44  45  72 210 162]
[205 246  19  68 118  44  72  45 210 162]
[205 246  19  68 118  44  45  72 210 162]
[246 205  19  68 118  44  72  45 210 162]
[205 246  19  68 118  44  72  45 210 162]
[205 246  19  68 118  44  72  45 210 162]
[205 246  19  68 118  44  72  45 210 162]
[205 246  19  68 118  44  72  45 210 162]
[205 246  19  68 118  44  72  45 210 162]
[205 246  19  68 118  44  72  45 210 162]
[205 246  19  68 118  44  72  45 210 162]
[205 246  19  68 118  44  72  45 210 162]
[205 246  19 118  44  68  72  45 210 162]
[205 246  19 118  68  44  72  45 210 162]
[205 246  19 118  68  44  72  45 210 162]
[205 246  19 118  68  44  72  45 210 162]
[205 246  19 118  68  44  72  45 210 162]
```

So my goal is to take the last line, then check how many times each number is repeated in all the notepad file.

For example, this is my last line  `[205 246  19 118  68  44  72  45 210 162]`. I need to plot my histogram based on the number of repetition of each number in all the file.
I need than to extract its rank:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fileHandle = open('path_File',"rb" )
lineList = fileHandle.readlines()
fileHandle.close()
print (lineList)
print ("The last line is:")
print (lineList[-1])
```

I extract from this code the last line, but I can't compute the repetition of each number in all the file, how to plot the histogram based on that?

Comment: Does the file have those brackets too?

Comment: Does the ordering matter? (example last line and first line differ only by the ordering of integers)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ If you are talking about this [] , so yes. thank you in advance

Comment: @PrestonM  In fact they  are random  numbers, so order is not  important.

Comment: @tierrytestu so in your example, you would want a histogram of the number of occurrences of 205, 246, 19, etc. in the file. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using the pandas library:

```
import StringIO #python3: io
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

string = """[205 246  19  68 118  44  45  72 210 162]
[205 246  19  68 118  44  45  72 210 162]
[205 246  19  68 118  44  45  72 210 162]
[205 246  19  68 118  44  72  45 210 162]
[205 246  19  68 118  44  45  72 210 162]
[246 205  19  68 118  44  72  45 210 162]
[205 246  19  68 118  44  72  45 210 162]
[205 246  19  68 118  44  72  45 210 162]
[205 246  19  68 118  44  72  45 210 162]
[205 246  19  68 118  44  72  45 210 162]
[205 246  19  68 118  44  72  45 210 162]
[205 246  19  68 118  44  72  45 210 162]
[205 246  19  68 118  44  72  45 210 162]
[205 246  19  68 118  44  72  45 210 162]
[205 246  19 118  44  68  72  45 210 162]
[205 246  19 118  68  44  72  45 210 162]
[205 246  19 118  68  44  72  45 210 162]
[205 246  19 118  68  44  72  45 210 162]
[205 246  19 118  68  44  72  45 210 162]"""

# Here we clean the file from [] and spaces " " creating a generator
clean = (i.strip()[1:-1].split() for i in StringIO.StringIO(string)) #py3 io.String...()

# But this code here is what you want to comment out and modify 
#with open("path/to/file.txt") as f:
#    clean = (i.strip()[1:-1].split() for i in f.readlines())

# Create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(clean)

# Counts all items and put them in a dict
dict_count = df.apply(pd.value_counts).sum(axis=1).to_dict()

# Dict with last row count (based on dict_count)
dict_values = {i:dict_count[i] for i in df.tail(1).values[0].tolist()}

# Plot a bar?
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010869/python-plot-a-bar-using-matplotlib-using-a-dictionary
plt.bar(range(len(dict_values)), dict_values.values(), align='center')
plt.xticks(range(len(dict_values)), dict_values.keys())

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do but my data is extracted from a file: So it gives me this error:      clean = (i.strip()[1:-1].split() for i in io.StringIO(lineList))
TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes

Comment: I guess you are using py2, so I changed the code slightly. The graph gets a strange look though. But the idea is correct.

Comment: I am sure that it gives me the correct solutions, the problem is when I change the  string with my data from the file: fileHandle = open('Path_File.txt',"r" )
string = fileHandle.readlines()
print (string),  So I got this error  TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not list
, when I put the string as /you have declared it, the code works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is an array where each element is a line from your file.
If all your lines are formatted the same way (and it seems it is), you can loop over all the lines and use a counter.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fileHandle = open('path_File',"rb" )
lineList = fileHandle.readlines()
fileHandle.close()
print (lineList)
print ("The last line is:")
print (lineList[-1]) 
count = 0
# The [:-1] says that you take all the values but the last one
for line in lineList[:-1]:
    if line == lineList[-1]:
        count += 1
```

If instead you want to check for each number in the last line, how many time they are repeated, you need to split lines. You can use the `split` function on your strings. Be careful, since you have brackets in each line, just remove the first and last character:

```
last_line = lineList[-1][1:-1].split(" ")
# This means, I want to split the last item of lineList
# with the space character " " as a separator. Also, i don't
# want the first and last character ([1:-1])
```

Then do the same in the loop:

```
# Initialize an array of counters for each element in last_line
counters = [0] * len(last_line)
for line in lineList[:-1]:
    line = line[1:-1].split(" ")
    for i in range(len(last_line)):
        if line[i] == last_line[i]:
            counters[i] += 1
```

Then If you want to plot an histogram, look at there : https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/pyplots/pyplot_text.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pyplots-pyplot-text-py

https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist

Comment: I found this error:     last_line = lineList[-1][1:-1].split(" ")
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Comment: you should then change fileHandle = open('path_File',"rb" ) by fileHandle = open('path_File',"r" ). You don't need to open your file in binary mode if it is in plain text.