# How to plot a tuple or list of values for each dictionary key using plt.bar

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-science, data-analysis

I already know about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010869/python-plot-a-bar-using-matplotlib-using-a-dictionary) and it worked perfectly, but with only one value in each key of the dictionary. So for example this worked:

```
dictionary = {'group_1': 50, 'group_2': 70, 'group_3': 80}
```

But what I wanted is to graph a bar using two values for each key so I can get side by side comparisons:

```
dictionary = {'group_2': (50, 60), 'group_2': (70, 40), 'group_3': (80, 20)}
```

If I try to plot the bar graph using these values, I get a

```
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

So this is the kind of graph that I want
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here: [plt.bar](https://pythonspot.com/matplotlib-bar-chart/). Where you have the `index` you select the keys from your dictionaries. Then the second element after `index, 'means_frank'` can be the slice (first two values) from the first or *n* dictionary.

Comment: Thank you. The link that you pointed me to had exactly what I want.

Comment: Great! Glad to help, actually I will use it also so was win-win.