# Generate Dayfiles from a complet list

Tags: python, list, append

maybe someone has a good idea.
I had generate a complete list of all gz files between to timestamps.
The list looks like that:

```
/media/PROJEKTE_SHARE/2019/2019-07-29/wind_reconstruction_data/23-00/WLS200s-92_WindReconstructionData_2019-07-29_23-59-31_DBS_26_50m.csv.gz
/media/PROJEKTE_SHARE/2019/2019-07-29/wind_reconstruction_data/23-00/WLS200s-92_WindReconstructionData_2019-07-29_23-59-50_DBS_26_50m.csv.gz
/media/PROJEKTE_SHARE/2019/2019-07-30/wind_reconstruction_data/00-00/WLS200s-92_WindReconstructionData_2019-07-30_00-00-46_DBS_26_50m.csv.gz
/media/PROJEKTE_SHARE/2019/2019-07-30/wind_reconstruction_data/00-00/WLS200s-92_WindReconstructionData_2019-07-30_00-01-06_DBS_26_50m.csv.gz
```

If I want to plot a plot for every day I first have to append them together. This is easy if I have only one day.
Actually I have no idea how to split the list and generate after that a dayfile for plotting them...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count occurence of files against each date. Then use [`matplotlib`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010869/plot-a-bar-using-matplotlib-using-a-dictionary) to plot aggregated dict.

```
from collections import Counter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

counts = Counter([f.split("/")[4] for f in files]).items()
# dict_items([('2019-07-29', 2), ('2019-07-30', 2)])

plt.bar(*zip(*counts))
plt.show()
```

---

[image]

Comment: Creat... Thank you :D