# python: histogram bars are attached to one another with the same height

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I am trying to plot a dictionary on a histogram.
The problem with the following code is that all bars are plotted
with equal heights despite having different values.
(see image)
Moreover, If I increase this dictionary with 5 times as many entries, the histogram looks like a big rectangle since the bars are not separated from one another.
(see image)
I have tried to change different parameters into this code but it did not solve these issues.

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    dict_1={'a123456': 3000, 'b123456': 3600, 'c13456': 3700, 'd123456': 4000}
    
    plt.hist(dict_1)
    plt.xticks(size = 10, rotation='vertical')
    plt.margins(0.05)
    plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.01)
    plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: `plt.bar(*zip(*dict_1.items()))`... see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53432195/9245853).

Comment: `plt.bar(x=dict_1.keys(), height=dict_1.values())`