# How to make a barplot not based of labels?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart, linestyle

I don't have a dummy code so I will try to explain it as good as I can. If no success I will try to think of a code to make it more clear.

My question is regarding making a barplot. I'd like to make a plot that instead of having the traditional solid line that goes from point to point, would instead have bars starting from the min value of the plot (let's say 0) to the value at that index.
So for every tick on the x axis there is a bar trace.

All barplot examples that I have seen are using labels as x axis (i.e. [Plot a bar using matplotlib using a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010869/plot-a-bar-using-matplotlib-using-a-dictionary)) but in my case I don't want my x axis to be a label but rather the index of a dataframe.

I have tried to implement the barplot but I usually get an error.
The first pic is what I have and it is a more classic type of plot. The second pic is what I'd like to have with the green traces (added manually) being the type of linestyle that I want.
I couldn't find anything online but it seemed weird that no one does this type of plots...
[figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMmH2.png)

[figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoxGB.png)

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible input for clarity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear, do you just want to use [`plot.bar`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html)?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'value': [0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 5, 4, 6, 3, 3, 0, 1, 4, 3, 0, 0]})

ax = plt.subplot()
df.plot(ax=ax)      # line plot
df.plot.bar(ax=ax)  #  bar plot
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I wanted to do! Thanks you!
Do know perhaps what would be the syntax if I would use the plot.bar() function in a subplot?
I tried ax.plot.bar() but it didn't work...

Comment: You can chose in which as to plot with `df.plot.bar(ax=name_of_your_ax)`